# Set dict value to the number of times it's inserted python?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I'm dealing with a list of games and wanted to find out which player won the most games using python. I figured a multiset (C++) type data structure would make it easy as each key is unique but it keeps count of how many times an item was pushed in the dict. I started implementing it myself after I failed to find anything talking about them in searches.

Is there an easier way where you can set a dict value to be the count of how many times the key is added instead of using a list like I did?

```
## logFiles is just a list of json files for each game.
winnerList = []
winnerDict = {}
if len(logFiles):
   for logFile in logFiles:
      jsonData = json.load(open("logs/" + logFile, 'r'))
      winnerList.append(str(jsonData[6]['winner']))
   for winner in winnerList:
      winnerDict[winner] = winnerList.count(winner)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections,json,os.path
winners = collections.Counter()
for logFile in logFiles:
    with open(os.path.join("logs", logFile), 'r') as jsonf:
        jsonData = json.load(jsonf)
    winner = str(jsonData[6]['winner'])
    winners[winner] += 1
winnerList = list(winners.keys())
bestPlayers = winners.most_common()
```

Comment: That looks great exactly what I wanted but I'm getting a traceback issue. When trying to use collections.Counter(), I guess I should say I'm running both python 2.5 and 2.6 on difference computers.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./topChamp.cgi", line 8, in <module>
        winners = collections.Counter()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'

Comment: For 2.5 support, you can simply copy [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dict.setdefault`

```
winnerDict = {}
if len(logFiles):
    for logFile in logFiles:
        jsonData = json.load(open("logs/" + logFile, 'r'))
        winner = str(jsonData[6]['winner'])
        winnerDict.setdefault(winner,0)
        winnerDict[winner] += 1
```